# How to wait until the Timer is finished? (animation using JAVA)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, repaint, timertask

I have made a class *BarberShopGUI* for the GUI animation of the sleeping barber problem. The animation can be run perfectly fine while a object is only need to do **one animation.** However, there are a few animation, like move to the sofa, move to the chair, move to the cashier and exit.
When any of two animation method is called

```
        this.moveGuestIn(0); // 0 for the customer id
        this.moveGuestToChair(0, 0); // (customer id, nth chair)
```

The animation would start concurrently, the object(customer0) is shaking because two method is controlling its axis (x, y).

Edit: Using the suggestion from Alex, I can now ignore any further animation request by using timer to mark whether the timer is finished. (and also a if-statement to check) However, I need to queue all the animation request rather than ignore it. Any suggestion please?

Edit 2: Updated by code by using the suggestion from Maurice Perry. Still testing.

Here is the code:

```
    public void moveGuestIn(int n)
    {
        Point p = new Point(200, 50);
        guests.get(n).moveTo(p);
    }
```

-

```
    @Override
    public synchronized void moveTo(final Point p)
    {
        if(timer != null)
            return;

        timer = new Timer(1000 / 60, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int delta = 0;
                if (bounds.x != p.x || bounds.y != p.y) {
                    delta = Math.abs(bounds.x - p.x);
                    delta = (delta >= 8) ? 8 : delta;
                    delta *= ((bounds.x - p.x) < 0) ? 1 : -1;
                    bounds.x += delta;

                    delta = Math.abs(bounds.y - p.y);
                    delta = (delta >= 8) ? 8 : delta;
                    delta *= ((bounds.y - p.y) < 0) ? 1 : -1;
                    bounds.y += delta;
                    repaint();
                } else {
                    timer.stop();
                    synchronized (Guest.this) {
                        timer = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }
```

All the codes:
[BarberShopGUI.java](http://www.codeshare.io/lpunv)

Comment: Use custom events to trigger the next animation. For simplicity, you could use `ActionEvent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would use a queue of animations, where an animation would implement some interface such as this one:

```
public interface Animation {
    public boolean isFinished();
    public void nextStep();
}
```

Then, the timer callback would get the animations one by one from a queue, execute them, and send a notification when the queue is empty:

```
private Queue<Animation> queue = new LinkedList<Animation>();

private Animation getUnfinishedAnimation() {
    synchronized(this) {
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Animation an = queue.peek();
            if (!an.isFinished()) {
                return an;
            }
            queue.poll();
            if (queue.isEmpty()) {
                notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private void nextAnimation() {
    synchronized(this) {
        queue.poll();
        if (queue.isEmpty()) {
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
}

private void timerTic() {
    Animation an = getUnfinishedAnimation();
    if (an != null) {
        an.nextStep();
        if (an.isFinished()) {
            nextAnimation();
        }
    }
}
```

You would need a method to add and animation to the queue, and another one to wait until the queue is empty:

```
public void scheduleAnimation(Animation a) {
    synchronized(this) {
        queue.add(a);
    }
}

public void waitQueueEmpty() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized(this) {
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Now moving a guest would become something like this:

```
public synchronized void moveTo(final Point p) {
    scheduleAnimation(new Animation() {
        @Override
        public boolean isFinished() {
            synchronized(Guest.this) {
                return bounds.x == p.x && bounds.y == p.y;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void nextStep() {
            synchronized(Guest.this) {
                int delta = Math.abs(bounds.x - p.x);
                delta = (delta >= 10) ? 10 : delta;
                delta *= ((bounds.x - p.x) < 0) ? 1 : -1;
                bounds.x += delta;

                delta = Math.abs(bounds.y - p.y);
                delta = (delta >= 10) ? 10 : delta;
                delta *= ((bounds.y - p.y) < 0) ? 1 : -1;
                bounds.y += delta;
            }
            repaint();
        }
    });
}
```

You can see that it is only scheduling the animation; so you would need to waitQueueEmpty() to let the scheduled animations go to completion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think your solution is the way to go! However, I've been worked for this about an hour, still can't figure out how to implement it in my application.. Here are a few questions that I have: 1.Since I have two class that share the same moveTo method, so I created a super class Animation, and try to add your code in inside that, is it right? 2.In fact, I have another class which implemented the sleeping barber algorithm which is used lots of Thread things, will it be affect if I create an instance in that class? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, you already had an Animation class. So there is now a name conflict. Why not call the interface Movement instead of Animation?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to control your application state at a higher level: you should not start a movement while another movement is in progress.

You simply assign timer now to a new timer instance. Try checking (in a synchronized way!) that timer is null before creating a new one. (And obviously make it null after stopping.)

```
    @Override
    public void moveTo(final Point p)
    {
        synchronized (this) {
            if(timer != null) {
                //ignore requests for new animations while in one
                return;
            }

            timer = new Timer(1000 / 60, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int delta = 0;
                    if (bounds.x != p.x || bounds.y != p.y) {
                        delta = Math.abs(bounds.x - p.x);
                        delta = (delta >= 10) ? 10 : delta;
                        delta *= ((bounds.x - p.x) < 0) ? 1 : -1;
                        bounds.x += delta;

                        delta = Math.abs(bounds.y - p.y);
                        delta = (delta >= 10) ? 10 : delta;
                        delta *= ((bounds.y - p.y) < 0) ? 1 : -1;
                        bounds.y += delta;
                        repaint();
                    } else {
                        timer.stop();
                        synchronized(Barber.this) {
                            timer = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you further explain how to do it in synchronized way? In fact, the method moveTo will be called by lots of **moveXXToXX** methods, if it is better to do something there??

Comment: In the code above I used the timer itself as a marker of an animation happening. The access to the variable has to be synchronized both when  assigning and nulling it.

Comment: Your idea with animationHappening marker is good, it allows not calling the function prematurely at all, in the first place. I would then create a  synchronized boolean isInAnimation() function to be able to check the current status of the object in a thread-safe way.

Comment: The code works! However, my goal is to **queue** the animation (maybe queue the timer) rather than cancel/ignore any animation request. Is there any way to wait? (I've tried few of common method to wait, however, lots of them is aiming to wait for operation but not animation, which make the screen cannot update while waiting.)

Comment: Again, this is a high-level design decision, rather than a technical Java question. When and why do you plan adding to the queue? What if you grow the queue faster than the animation can happen? Do you really need to plan that far ahead? Depends on the logic of the game (which I'm not familiar with, sorry). What's wrong with simple selecting the next move when the previous one has ended? (Not moving can be also considered animation with 0 change.)

Comment: There are few event to trigger the animation, the event would not  happened faster than the animation. Furthermore, there will be few of customer in the application, and what I want is, each of them have their own animations, and they will be disappeared after their animations is completed. However, when I try to use timer to do the animation, the animation just do not animate step-by-step, and so I want to queue the animation.

Comment: Are you sure you could serve all events by animations? What if there are more events that there is time to play all the animations, and the queue would grow indefinitely? You must decide for yourself, what are the constraints and how they are implemented, like: a) animation, once started, proceeds to the end, b) if at the end of an animation there are several events waiting, only the latest one triggers the new animation, the others are discarded. Then you don't need a queue, only the latest event that can be overwritten by a new one.

Comment: Then your system becomes event-driven, every actor processes incoming events. If in an animation already, actor puts the event as the "next thing to process", maybe replacing something else. If not in animation, a new animation is started.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the proper architecture is as follows:

- the animation thread listens for `ActionEvent`s, and updates the target position based on this. (Or queues them up as waypoints).
- when the animation is finished (e.g. an ActionEvent with "animation finished"), that is an event, too. Other listeners could use this to enable buttons etc.
- when a button is clicked etc., fire an event, and let the animation react to this, instead of manually starting the animation.

It's a best practise from Model-View-Controller to not tie UI into your program too much. Events are a good abstraction to achieve such separation. Instead of talking to each other, the parts both listen to events, and both may cause events. Even different UI components best talk to each other with events.

Comment: Hey, thanks for you advise. However, I'm doing a program that implement the Sleeping Barber Algorithm, which is using Threads to trigger the events...

Comment: So you are trying to produce a problem... then no, choosing a better architecture may of course cause the problem to disappear. ;-)